# What does an IPs meaning by within cluster and what is outside cluster in AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cloud, load-balancing, azure-aks

I have a cluster and pods running inside the cluser.

There are associated services for each pods and few are cluster IP, few are node port and few are load balancers.

I also have VM running in my azure account.

If i am hitting IP of these services/pods in this VMs browser.

What is considered a within-cluster what is considered an outside cluster? Means
why my load blancer ip only accessible in VMs chrome browser and no cluser IPs are not accessible within VMs chrome browser?
That means cluster ips are external and load balancer is internal?

Comment: "That means cluster ips are external and load balancer is internal?" No, it's the exact opposite

Answer (score 1):

`ClusterIP` service types are internal to your cluster. The IP address assigned to the service is from the `pod-network-cidr` which is an internal CIDR. You cannot reach a ClusterIP service from outside the cluster.

`NodePort` services are external and are bound to the IP address of the Node on a specified port. This is the IP address of the node that is "external" to it (pingable from the outside).

`LoadBalancer` services are external as well, and usually can be bound to various public IP addresses as required in order to properly load balance traffic to your services.

You can read more about service types [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

I hope this helps!